# The string becomes left-to-right When I write a number at the beginning of a string

Tags: python, format, special-characters, right-to-left, unicode-string

I have a number string and a Persian string that I want to concatenate in python (my IDE is Pycharm) and when I do this, right-to-left breaks down.

```
num = "1200"
body = "ریال"
total = num + " " + body
print(total)
```

it results:

> 1200 ریال

but I expect this:

> ‏1200 ریال

what can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a special standard character named [Right-to-left mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-to-left_mark).
you can use it with this expression:

> **u"\u200F"**

So you can correct your code this way:

```
corrected = u"\u200F" + num + " " + body
print(corrected)
```

that results:

> ‏1200 ریال

Answer (score 0):

the string isn't right to left, you're just adding the number first.
try:

```
total = body + " " + num
```

Comment: But 
total = num + " " + body 
dosn't results what you excpected.

Comment: exactly, total = body + " " + num does, total num + " " + body doesn't